# Background image compressed in Android browser

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

[image: Here is a screenshot from www.manymo.com]
Hi,

I'm having problem with Android default browser where the browser compresses the background image. In all other browsers this does not appear. You can check the site here: http://www.aidenapp.com

This far I have tested with three HTC Android devices and all have the same problem. With a Samsung tablet there was no such problem. I removed any width/height settings from the image and the image still had the same effect.

Could someone help please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some plugin to 'stretch' it? If not, you really need to have the image as an element? I mean, if you put it in your CSS as body background, and define the *background-size: cover*, it will render more correctly.

Comment: Yup, this replaced the "stretch" script and now it works better in mobile and in pc. Thanks!